How to run a simulation in Oracle ODI using Java APIs?
I want to interacti with Oracle Data Integrator 11g using the provided Java SDK.
I am able to connect to the ODI instance, but I do not know how to run a simulation from a selected intefrace.
Here is the code written so far:
        <performing connection>

        // Allocate an odisinstance of the name
        final OdiInstance odiInstance = odiInstanceHandle.getOdiInstance();
        try {
            TransactionTemplate tx = new TransactionTemplate(odiInstance.getTransactionManager());
            tx.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(ITransactionStatus pStatus) {
                    // Retrieve the interface you want to simulate
                    IOdiInterfaceFinder ifaceFinder = (IOdiInterfaceFinder) odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiInterface.class); 
                    OdiInterface iface = ifaceFinder.findByQualifiedName("your_interface_name");


I want to execute a simulation and capture the logs form the selected interface. It is that possible via the Java APIs?
I tried to create a Scenario and looked around the internet. I only found guides for ODI 12

Unfortunately there is no SDK method equivalent to the Simulation checkbox available through ODI Studio.
The only way to capture the logs programatically is to effectively run the interfaces / scenarios.
Generating a scenario can be done using the methods of IOdiScenarioGenerator interface :
IIOdiScenarioGenerator gene = new OdiScenarioGeneratorImpl((odiInstance);
OdiScenario newScen = gene.generateScenario(pPackage, "MYSCENARIO", "001");

Starting a scenario execution can be done with startScenario method of RuntimeAgent class.
